# xAxis.setLowerBound(1) is causing to disappear bar in bar chart in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I want xAxis values are from 1 to 10. When I set xAxis lowerBound to '1' instead of '0' bar in chart is disappearing.

```
NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
xAxis.setLowerBound(1);
xAxis.setUpperBound(10);
xAxis.setTickUnit(1);

final CategoryAxis yAxis = new CategoryAxis();
final BarChart<Number,String> bc =new BarChart<Number,String>(xAxis,yAxis);

XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, "XYZ"));
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this and it works for me.  I'm using java 8.

```
public class HorizBarChart extends Application {
@Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
    xAxis.setLowerBound(1);
    xAxis.setUpperBound(10);
    xAxis.setTickUnit(1);
    final CategoryAxis yAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    final BarChart<Number,String> bc = new BarChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);

    XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
    series1.setName("1");       
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, "XYZ"));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, "ABC"));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, "def"));
    Scene scene  = new Scene(bc,800,600);
    bc.getData().addAll(series1);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
}
```